# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object on Spatial Join

Tags: spatial-join, shapely, pandas, arcgis-python-api, quadtree

I'm working with two spatial dataframes and am trying to do a spatial join on the two.

parcels_sdf -- a frame with around ~370,000 real estate parcels.

subdivisions_sdf -- a frame with all approved subdivisions in my county.

Both frames appear to have non null values in their SHAPE columns which I believe means they have valid geometries (how to check for this?).   What I want to end up with is to associate all parcels with subdivisions when their geometry lies within the subdivision geometry.

```
parcels_sdf.info()
```

RangeIndex: 376926 entries, 0 to 376925
Data columns (total 60 columns):
OBJECTID                376926 non-null int64
PIN_NUM                  376893 non-null object
CALC_AREA                376926 non-null float64
REID                     376691 non-null object
MAP_NAME                 376691 non-null object
OWNER                    376691 non-null object
ADDR1                    376691 non-null object
ADDR2                    376684 non-null object
ADDR3                    16232 non-null object
.
.
.
LAND_CODE                376092 non-null object
SHAPE                376926 non-null geometry
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(21), geometry(1), int64(1), object(35)    memory usage: 172.5+ MB

```
subdivisions_sdf.info()
```

RangeIndex: 5503 entries, 0 to 5502
Data columns (total 18 columns):
OBJECTID            5503 non-null int64
ACCESS_RD           5351 non-null object
NAME                5503 non-null object
APPROVDATE          5190 non-null datetime64[ns]
ACRES               5503 non-null float64
.
.
LAST_EDITED_DATE    5503 non-null datetime64[ns]
SHAPE               5503 non-null geometry
dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(6), geometry(1), int64(1), object(7)
memory usage: 774.0+ KB

When I try to do the join:

```
joined_sdf = parcels_sdf.spatial.join(subdivisions_sdf, 
              how='inner', op='within', left_tag='parcel', right_tag='subdivision')
```

I get the following error:

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 joined_sdf = parcels_sdf.spatial.join(subdivisions_sdf, how='inner', op='within', left_tag='parcel', right_tag='subdivision')
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo_accessor.py in
>   join(self, right_df, how, op, left_tag, right_tag)    1089
>   left_df, right_df = right_df, left_df    1090 
>   -> 1091         tree_idx = right_df.spatial.sindex("quadtree")    1092     1093         idxmatch = (left_df[self.name]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo_accessor.py in
>   sindex(self, stype, reset, **kwargs)    2095
>   self._sindex.insert(oid=idx, bbox=gext)    2096
>   else:
>   -> 2097                         self._sindex.insert(oid=idx, bbox=g.geoextent)    2098                     if c >= int(l/4) + 1:
>   2099                         self._sindex.flush()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo_index_impl.py in
>   insert(self, oid, bbox)
>       108             return r
>       109         elif self._stype.lower() == 'quadtree':
>   --> 110             return self._index.insert(item=oid, bbox=bbox)
>       111         elif self._stype.lower() == 'custom':
>       112             r = self._index.intersect(oid, bbox)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo_index\quadtree.py
>   in insert(self, item, bbox)
>       237         - **bbox**: The spatial bounding box tuple of the item, with four members (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
>       238         """
>   --> 239         self._insert(item, bbox)
>       240 
>       241     def intersect(self, bbox):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo_index\quadtree.py
>   in _insert(self, item, bbox)
>        85 
>        86     def _insert(self, item, bbox):
>   ---> 87         rect = _normalize_rect(bbox)
>        88         if len(self.children) == 0:
>        89             node = _QuadNode(item, rect)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\geo_index\quadtree.py
>   in _normalize_rect(rect)
>        40 
>        41 def _normalize_rect(rect):
>   ---> 42     x1, y1, x2, y2 = rect
>        43     if x1 > x2:
>        44         x1, x2 = x2, x1
>
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Based on the error which appears to be in the quadtree module, I think this means there is bad data in my right frame (subdivisions_sdf).   But, I can't seem to find a way to troubleshoot.   See anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did I post this on the wrong forum?  Should this have been on SO python forum as its both GIS/spatial related but its a python pandas question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got back a very helpful response from my County (Wake, NC) GIS help desk.  Brandon guided me to the solution:  "As to your other point, the multi-part polygon issue could be solved by dissolving the shapes (Dissolve in ArcGIS or Dissolve in GeoPandas). Dissolve will combine disparate polygons together based on an attribute field – in this case, the PIN_NUM field. That will create a dataset that loses the rest of the parcel attributes, but they can be easily joined back to the new dataset."

I was able to determine that I had some shapes with multiple polygons (I think this is referred to as the bowtie problem).   I ended up converting the ArcGIS SDF to a standard Geopandas dataframe and then did the dissolve and spatial join.

[image: example of bad shape that wouldn't join from gis sdf]

This worked for me:

```
import geopandas as gpd
#parcels_sdf is a spatially enhanced dataframe generated from a layer of an ARCGIS server
parcels_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(parcels_sdf, geometry= "SHAPE")
parcels_dissolved = parcels_gdf.dissolve(by='PIN_NUM')
parcels_dissolved.geometry.is_valid.value_counts()
```

> True     374736 False      2211 dtype: int64

I still got invalid geometries but the spatial join runs

```
joined_gdf = gpd.sjoin(parcels_dissolved, subdivisions_gdf, op='within', how='inner', lsuffix='parcel', rsuffix='subd')
```